# RecyclerView not visible inside NestedScrollView in android

Tags: android-recyclerview

I am trying to hiding toolbar when scrolling. Using CoordinatorLayout ,TabLayout, Viewpager.

Comment: Please let us know what have you tried by posting your code or error message, etc..